# How to define logging level in Sentry Python SDK

Tags: python, django, sentry

```py
python 3.5
sentry-sdk 0.8.0
```

Hello,

I'm trying to get in Sentry.io some informations (INFO level) coming from a view in Django and I'm not sure to understand how to make it. This is what I have tried :

In settings.py

```py
sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(
    level=logging.INFO,        
    event_level=logging.INFO
)
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://###",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), sentry_logging],
    server_name="MyServerName",
)
```

In views.py

```py
def myview(request, something):
    # Here I do something

    # Log some data
    logger.info('Interesting info !', extra={
         'something_modified': something_modified,
    })
```

With this code, I don't see my event info in Sentry. If I call logger.error(###) it shows this event and I have the red "error" flag, like expected with error level.

So I tried :

```py
def myview(request, something):
    # Here I do something

    # Log some data
    with configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.level = 'info'
        logger.info('Interesting info !', extra={
            'something_modified': something_modified,
        })
```

- It doesn't work either
- With logger.error(###) it shows this event and I have a blue info flag in Sentry
- But the other real errors now appear in blue too, which is a bit too monochrome

Some concepts from the documentation are still unclear for me, I may have mixed "context / scope / levels" together.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the level of your logger to INFO:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```